# Error in headerfile - stdint.h in codeblocks while building AVR PROJECT

Tags: c, embedded, codeblocks, avr, avr-gcc

I'm getting a error in stdint.h file, while building the AVR project.  Here I'm trying to simulate different driving modes in a car such as comfort, eco and sports mode. I never thought I would get error like this, is this because of some configuration error, can someone help me? I have attached the actual code here [driving modes](https://github.com/saravanan849/DRIVING-MODES)

Here is the buildlog:

```
-------------- Clean: Debug in driving modes (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler for AVR)---------------

Cleaned "driving modes - Debug"

-------------- Build: Debug in driving modes (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler for AVR)---------------

avr-gcc.exe -Wall -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000UL -g -IC:\WinAVR\avr\include -c adc.c -o obj\Debug\adc.o
avr-gcc.exe -Wall -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000UL -g -IC:\WinAVR\avr\include -c comfort.c -o obj\Debug\comfort.o
avr-gcc.exe -Wall -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000UL -g -IC:\WinAVR\avr\include -c eco.c -o obj\Debug\eco.o
avr-gcc.exe -Wall -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000UL -g -IC:\WinAVR\avr\include -c fuse.c -o obj\Debug\fuse.o
In file included from c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/inttypes.h:37,
                 from c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/avr/sfr_defs.h:126,
                 from c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/avr/io.h:99,
                 from adc.h:16,
                 from adc.c:14:
c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/stdint.h:121: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'typedef'
c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/stdint.h:159: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int_least8_t'
c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/stdint.h:213: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int_fast8_t'
In file included from c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/inttypes.h:37,
                 from c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/avr/sfr_defs.h:126,
                 from c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/avr/io.h:99,
                 from GPIO.h:16,
                 from comfort.c:13:
c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/stdint.h:121: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'typedef'
c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/stdint.h:159: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int_least8_t'
c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/stdint.h:213: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int_fast8_t'
In file included from GPIO.h:17,
                 from comfort.c:13:
c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/util/delay.h:90:3: warning: #warning "Compiler optimizations disabled; functions from <util/delay.h> won't work as designed"
In file included from comfort.c:14:
adc.h:22: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'extern'
In file included from comfort.c:15:
pwm.h:22: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'extern'
In file included from comfort.c:16:
comfort.h:29: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'extern'
comfort.c: In function 'comfort':
comfort.c:32: error: 'ADC_VALUE' undeclared (first use in this function)
comfort.c:32: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
comfort.c:32: error: for each function it appears in.)
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
 
In file included from adc.h:17,
                 from adc.c:14:
c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/util/delay.h:90:3: warning: #warning "Compiler optimizations disabled; functions from <util/delay.h> won't work as designed"
adc.c: In function 'adc_config':
adc.c:30: warning: implicit declaration of function 'sei'
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
 
In file included from c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/inttypes.h:37,
                 from c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/avr/sfr_defs.h:126,
                 from c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/avr/io.h:99,
                 from GPIO.h:16,
                 from eco.c:13:
c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/stdint.h:121: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'typedef'
c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/stdint.h:159: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int_least8_t'
c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/stdint.h:213: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int_fast8_t'
In file included from GPIO.h:17,
                 from eco.c:13:
c:/winavr-20100110/lib/gcc/../../avr/include/util/delay.h:90:3: warning: #warning "Compiler optimizations disabled; functions from <util/delay.h> won't work as designed"
In file included from eco.c:14:
adc.h:22: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'extern'
In file included from eco.c:15:
pwm.h:22: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'extern'
In file included from eco.c:16:
eco.h:29: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'void'
eco.c: In function 'eco':
eco.c:32: error: 'ADC_VALUE' undeclared (first use in this function)
eco.c:32: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
eco.c:32: error: for each function it appears in.)
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
 
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
21 error(s), 4 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: The error is unlikely in a standard header file, it's more likely that you do something wrong in one of your files, somewhere before you include one the standard header files.

Comment: Could you post the content of `include/stdint.h` around line `121` ? `winavr-2010` - maybe try a newer version, from this decade ;) [Is this the source](https://github.com/eerimoq/avr-toolchain-windows/blob/master/avr/include/stdint.h#L121)?

Comment: @KamilCuk yeah that's the source, when I build other projects it is not showing this error. Line 121 has same code that you mentioned.

Comment: Then try to proceed as follows: Remove stuff from source files until you are left with the most minimal [MCVE]. Does a single file with just single `#include `reproduces? What is the _minimal_ source file for the problem? Does a single file reproduces? Does the file reproduce the problem when compiled manually outside of cmake? Etc. proceed, until you find the line that causes problems.

Comment: A similar problem with the same three lines 121,159 and 213 implicated at https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/solved-stdint-errors.  There it was a typo on the top-level including code (as is invariably the case with theses things).

Comment: Something in the code prior to including adc.h I would presume.  Especially since the later errors such as `adc.h:22: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'extern'` do not even reference stdint.h or any standard header - just your eco.c code.  Looks like whatever you are doing wrong it is a habit or duplicated across your code.  You need to show the code eco.c up to line 16 at least and eco.h up to line 29. You have similar issues elsewhere, but I am willing to bet it is the same error in each case.

Comment: I have included three asterisk at the start of the code unknowingly and duplicated this format to all other .h files, that's the reason. Thank you all

Comment: all other errors are corrected, but now I'm getting this one

Comment: ```avr-gcc.exe -LC:\WinAVR\avr\lib -o "bin\Debug\driving modes.elf" obj\Debug\adc.o obj\Debug\comfort.o obj\Debug\eco.o obj\Debug\fuse.o obj\Debug\GPIO.o obj\Debug\interrupt.o obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\modes.o obj\Debug\panic.o obj\Debug\pwm.o obj\Debug\sport.o  -mmcu=atmega328p -Wl,-Map=bin\Debug\driving modes.map,--cref  
avr-gcc.exe: modes.map,--cref: No such file or directory
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: In case the gcc port is older than version 5.0.0, you might need an explicit `-std=c99` or equivalent, or it might not know if the stdint.h header. Older gcc defaults to C90.

Comment: You should probably close the question yourself - it serves no community purpose without the information required to make it answerable (comments don't count).

Comment: @saravanan : Different error, different question.  This is not a discussion forum and your new issue should not be dealt with in comments related to a different question.  Again though it is a matter of reading and understanding the error messages: `avr-gcc.exe: modes.map,--cref: No such file or directory` - it is telling you that there is not file called `"modes.map,--cref"` - and it is correct.  That comma should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

I have included three asterisk at the start of the code unknowingly and duplicated this format to all other .h files, that's why I got this error. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

`Something in the code prior to including adc.h I would presume. Especially since the later errors such as adc.h:22: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'extern' do not even reference stdint.h or any standard header - just your eco.c code. Looks like whatever you are doing wrong it is a habit or duplicated across your code. You need to show the code eco.c up to line 16 at least and eco.h up to line 29. You have similar issues elsewhere, but I am willing to bet it is the same error in each case.`
This answer came from @Clifford

Comment: Do you see this little [edit] link below your question and answers? It is meant to be used...